# C/C++ code using pthreads to execute sync and async communications

Tags: c, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, pthreads

I am using a Linux machine to communicate with a PLC. The PLC and Linux-machine are connected within a **local network**, and use UDP/IP as the base protocol. Also, the port number is **fixed** on both sides.

Such a communication needs to achieve:
*Requirement 1*: Linux machine could send commands (one command each time) to the PLC. After each command received, the PLC will response the Linux machine with a success/failure message within 50ms.
*Requirement 2*: Vise versa, PLC could send commands to the Linux machine. The Linux machine has to response back with a message within 50ms. The PLC sending is **asynchronous** to the Linux machine. Therefore the Linux machine needs to monitor(or listen to) the port continuously.

Simple C/C++ code has been used for testing the communication separately regarding the aforementioned requirements. It worked. But blocking mechanism was conducted.

Here comes the challenging part. I would like to use pthreads for such a communication. My solution is to simply create two threads for each requirement. I sketched my thought using the attached pic [https://www.dropbox.com/s/vriyrprl7j6tntx/multi-thread%20solution.png?dl=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91gda.png), with 'thread 0' denoting **main thread**, 'thread 1' denoting  **Requirement 1 thread** and 'thread 2' denoting **Requirement 2 thread**. 'shared data' indicates the data that could be shared throughout all the child threads. 'thread 1 data' is dedicated for thread 1 usage, and other threads will not access. Likewise, 'thread 2 data' is only used by thread 2.

My concern rises considering two threads will be conducting system calls on the same port. Hence, I need reviews on my solution, and it would be awesome to get more working solutions. P.S. I am not too worried about thread synchronization and creation. And it is totally cool to me if thread sync and creation are necessary in your solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to ask open ended questions like this. But some thoughts. You haven't really given any strong reason for going to a threaded architecture. Closest I can see is the old solution was a "blocking mechanism" and you want to avoid that. But avoiding a particular mechanism should not be an end goal. What is it about the "blocking mechanism" (that you already says works) that is problematic (e.g. did it not meet timing requirements)? To reach a solution one must first understand what problems are bring addressed. Only then can we decide if threading makes sense or not.

Comment: Do note that threading is not required for implementing an asynchronous architecture.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for you response. I need to make some specifications.

Comment: @kaylum 1. Responsiveness is one of the performance criteria I need to consider. Yes, the async communication needs to be handled within a time limit. Multi-threading is one of the ways to ease the tense caused by timing requirements.

Comment: @kaylum 2. The blocking mechanism, to be more specific, is to use sendto() and revcfrom()  system calls. In my application, sendto() is invoked by higher-layer classes periodically. revcfrom() will be used: firstly to get the success/failure response from the PLC; secondly, to receive async messages from the PLC, which are urgent request.

Comment: @kaylum 3. I disagree with the opinion " threading is not required for implementing an asynchronous architecture". I suppose modern servers use multi-threading for monitoring client requests (which are asynchronous) in one thread, and processing the requests in another. Or could you define 'asynchronous architecture' properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general problem with two threads executing system calls on the same socket.  You may encounter some specific issues, though:

- If you call `recvfrom()` in both threads (one waiting for the PLC to send a request, and the other waiting for the PLC to respond to a command from the server), you don't know which one will receive the response.  To get around this, you can dedicate one thread to reading from the PLC, and have it pass reply messages from the PLC to the sending thread using shared queue or similar structure.
- You have to be careful when you close a socket that could be in use by another thread - because of the way file descriptors are reused, it's easy to have a race condition that ends up with a thread acting on the wrong socket.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.